# In pandas, set a new column and update existing column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a `pandas` dataframe, I have a last name field that looks like

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['Jones Jr', 'Smith'], columns=['LastName'])
```

I am trying to set a new column named 'Generation', while stripping out the Generation for the last name, so the outcome would look like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([('Jones', 'Jr'), ('Smith', '')], columns=['LastName', 'Generation'])
```

I could set the Generation column then go back and remove the Generation from the last name:

```
df.loc[df['LastName'].str[-3:] == ' Jr', 'Generation'] = 'Jr'
df.loc[df['LastName'].str[-3:] == ' Jr', 'LastName'] = df['LastName'].str[:-3]
```

However, that's two steps and it seems like performing an update in one swoop would be best.

I thought about apply, but it's an apply to two columns where matching X and I couldn't find anything close to that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [.str.extract()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method:

```
In [19]: df2 = df.LastName.str.extract(r'(?P<LastName>\w+)\s?(?P<Generation>Jr|Sr)?', expand=True)

In [20]: df2
Out[20]:
  LastName Generation
0    Jones         Jr
1    Smith        NaN
```

Comment: You can name the columns as well, e.g. `df.LastName.str.extract(r"(?P<LastName>\w+)\s?(?P<Generation>Jr|Sr?)", expand = True)`